# How to reference other ViewControllers in Delegate rather than just root

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to create a Siri Shortcut & I want the shortcut to go to a different ViewController rather than just the root. How is that done? The following is the current App Delegate code.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

            print(userActivity.activityType)//com.myvisionapps.Meditate.begin
            if(userActivity.activityType == "com.myvisionapps.Meditate.begin") {
                if let controller = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {

                }

            }

            return false


        }
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code AppDelegate and its gone be okey:

```
let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewControlleripad : yourViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerIdentifire") as! yourViewController
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
// now you can use initialViewControlleripad to access to your references in your ViewController
```

Comment: Which ViewController is "yourViewController"?

Comment: Any ViewController that you want to access to references